# Shopping list for developing iOS apps on Windows

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, mobile, vmware

This is pretty much the exact opposite question of [Shopping list for developing Windows app on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611391/shopping-list-for-developing-windows-app-on-mac)

We are running VMWare in a corporate environment. I'm looking to write a hybrid app with Cordova, compile it and deploy it to the Apple App Store through an instance of a Mac OS. We're obviously willing to purchase whatever licenses are required.

So I'd like to know if it's possible, and how, to buy, then download an image of the latest Mac OS, mount it and install it through the VM?

Comment: People are probably doing this exact same thing every day. Why no answers? :/

Comment: Please update your question to be more specific. A shopping list is not a question, but in the details you are asking how to install MacOS in VMWare (which has little to do with iOS development). Please be specific about what you need help with and what your desired outcome is.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665682/iphone-dev-on-windows-using-vmware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159/is-it-possible-to-run-mac-os-x-in-a-virtual-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't legally run Mac OS X in a VM on Windows. Apple does not sell licenses to do that. OS X is only licensed to run on Apple hardware. You can of course pirate OS X, patch VMWare and then run it on Windows. This is unsupported though and not everything might work.

You will have to buy a Mac, probably a Mac mini is best.

Comment: Legality is a law matter, and licenses are not laws. Independently by what a software license says, you need to check your country laws to understand what you can or can't do with a software.

Comment: IANAL. The validity of software licenses is often unclear, that's true. However copyright law applies in any case. Apple does not sell OS X 10.9 in a box or on physical media. You can only get a copy of OS X 10.9 with an Apple computer or from the Mac App Store, which only runs on OS X. Obtaining it with other means would probably mean copyright infringement. But because Apple gives copies away for free, it could be argued that no damage is done to Apple. Pirating free (as is beer) software sounds a bit silly.

Comment: I understand your point of view but saying "You can't LEGALLY run Mac OSX in a VM on Windows [BECAUSE] Apple does not sell licenses to do that." is simply a wrong inference.

I always buy the software I use and I'm not suggesting to steal or pirate anything. Said that, EULA is not law: it's a one-way agreement and it's not signed, so it has no legal validity, at least here in Italy. I continue to suggest to check country laws about what you can or can't do with a software you regularly bought. In the case of drminnaar, the check is even more important because he is in a corporate environment.